# How does "rain/snow/hail won't fall" make sense?

Tags: logic

Rain, snow, and hail all are something that falls by definition. So saying "rain, snow and hail won't fall" is against consistency, I mean, logic. I think "there will be no rain, snow and hail" or  "it won't rain, snow and hail" is a correct expression. Nonetheless why do people keep saying "rain, snow and hail won't fall"?

Comment: You say "people keep saying" those things, but it's much _more_ common to say _It won't rain_ or _No rain will fall_ if you are just talking about tomorrow's weather.

Comment: "The fire won't start" How can we use "the" with something that doesn't exist?

Comment: "Nonetheless why do people keep saying "rain, snow and hail won't fall" Says who? Where? Please provide a source for your allegations.

Comment: The answer(s) to the older question are the same as James K's here.

Answer (score 5):

These are easily understood.  "Snow won't fall tomorrow" is equivalent to saying "It won't snow tomorrow".  Natural languages are not formal languages of logic and there is no problem with such sentences.

In English and many European languages the verb form is preferred for weather events "It won't snow".  In other languages (including most Asian languages) only the noun form "Snow won't fall" is possible.

It is probably the same in your language.

<sub>In Korean, for example the idea "Snow isn't falling" is formed with the word for snow and taking the stem of verb for "come down" adding "ji" and the negative auxiliary *anta*, in its appropriate conjugation. This proves that there is no special treatment of this in English.</sub>

Comment: You mean, Do natural language not need to be strictly logical?

Comment: Of course not.  Do you think your native language is "strictly logical"!? If you do, I have news for you....